# change look-and-feel of plot to resemble hist

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I used the information from this post to create a histogram with logarithmic scale:
[Histogram with Logarithmic Scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245273/histogram-with-logarithmic-scale)

However, the output from plot looks nothing like the output from hist. Does anyone know how to configure the output from plot to resemble the output from hist? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simplified, reproducible version of the linked answer is

```
x <- rlnorm(1000)
hx <- hist(x, plot=FALSE)
plot(hx$counts, type="h", log="y", lwd=10, lend="square")
```

To get the axes looking more "hist-like", replace the last line with

```
plot(hx$counts, type="h", log="y", lwd=10, lend="square", axes = FALSE)
Axis(side=1)
Axis(side=2)
```

Getting the bars to join up is going to be a nightmare using this method.  I suggest using trial and error with values of `lwd` (in this example, 34 is somewhere close to looking right), or learning to use `lattice` or `ggplot`.

---

EDIT:
You can't set a border colour, because the bars aren't really rectangles – they are just fat lines.  We can fake the border effect by drawing slightly thinner lines over the top.  The updated code is

```
par(lend="square")
bordercol <- "blue"
fillcol <- "pink"
linewidth <- 24
plot(hx$counts, type="h", log="y", lwd=linewidth, col=bordercol, axes = FALSE)
lines(hx$counts, type="h", lwd=linewidth-2, col=fillcol)
Axis(side=1)
Axis(side=2)
```

Comment: I ended up with using lwd=24. I also changed the color of the bars using the col-attribute. It seems impossible to also add borders to the bars. Or in any case it says that the border-attribute is not a valid graphics parameter.

Answer (score 1):

How about using ggplot2?

```
x <- rnorm(1000)
qplot(x) + scale_y_log10()
```

But I agree with Hadley's comment on the other post that having a histogram with a log scale seems weird to me =).

Comment: unfortunately I don't have the liberty to install ggplot2 in the environment I'm working in