# Make y-axis logarithmic in histogram using R

Tags: r, histogram, logarithm

Hi I'm making histogram using R, but the number of Y axis is so large that I need to turn it into logarithmic.See below my script:

```
hplot<-read.table("libl")
hplot
pdf("first_end")
hist(hplot$V1, breaks=24, xlim=c(0,250000000), ylim=c(0,2000000),main="first end mapping", xlab="Coordinates")
dev.off()
```

So how should I change my script?
thx

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have a logarithmic y-axis on a histogram - the bars extend down to 0, which on the log-scale is negative infinity.

Comment: It doesn't make sense from that perspective but if you have nothing at zero and you want to show that a set of data has more than one mode occurring a different values between say 18000 and 35000 with the majority at 25000, the log transformation shows this nicely without having the frequency axis so large that it "washes" out the modes at other values.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can save the histogram data to tweak it before plotting:

```
set.seed(12345)
x = rnorm(1000)

hist.data = hist(x, plot=F)
hist.data$counts = log10(hist.data$counts)

dev.new(width=4, height=4)
hist(x)

dev.new(width=4, height=4)
plot(hist.data, ylab='log10(Frequency)')
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a little misleading because you have shifted the baseline from 0 to 10^0 = 1.

Comment: @hadley Yea I think it's strange too. There's a reason you can't just pass `log='y'` like a normal plot.

Comment: Worked nicely, just dev.new(width=4, height=4) didn't work saying "In (function ()  : Only one RStudio graphics device is permitted" as I am using RStudio.

Comment: @saganas yeah you can skip those in rstudio, the UI let's you navigate between plots

Comment: Hey John Colby, I was able to get your solution to work for something similar I am doing. However, I cannot seem to match the x-labels with the breaks I need. Maybe that's not possible in Base R. How would I use the hist.data in ggplot?

Answer (score 4):

Another option would be to use `plot(density(hplot$V1), log="y")`.

It's not a histogram, but it shows just about the same information, and it avoids the illogical part where a bin with zero counts is not well-defined in log-space.

Of course, this is only relevant when your data is continuous and not when it's really categorical or ordinal.

Answer (score 3):

A histogram with the y-axis on the log scale will be a rather odd histogram. Technically it will still fit the definition, but it could look rather misleading: the peaks will be flattened relative to the rest of the distribution.

Instead of using a log transformation, have you considered:

- Dividing the counts by 1 million:

  `h <- hist(hplot$V1, plot=FALSE)`

  `h$counts <- h$counts/1e6`

  `plot(h)`
- Plotting the histogram as a density estimate:

  `hist(hplot$V1, freq=FALSE)`

Comment: A histogram with the y-axis in log scale is a rather common thing, specially if you want to take care of the tails, rare events that take extreme values. A reply to a similar question you can find it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245273/histogram-with-logarithmic-scale

Answer (score 2):

You can log your y-values for the plot and add a custom log y-axis afterwards.

Here is an example for a table object of random normal distribution numbers:

```
# data
count = table(round(rnorm(10000)*2))
# plot
plot(log(count) ,type="h",  yaxt="n", xlab="position", ylab="log(count)")
# axis labels
yAxis = c(0,1,10,100,1000)
# draw axis labels
axis(2, at=log(yAxis),labels=yAxis, las=2)
```

[image: log data with log axis labeling]