# Plotting Logscale in R's curve()

Tags: r, plot

I have a data which I want to plot in cumulative function.

The R code I have is the following:

```
dat <- read.table("evalues_point.txt" )
pre.test <- dat$V1
print (pre.test)

pre.ecdf <- ecdf(pre.test)
rx <- range(pre.test)
ry <- max(length(pre.test))


curve(length(pre.test)*(1-pre.ecdf(x)), from=rx[1], to=rx[2], col="red", xlim=rx, ylim=c(0,ry))
```

With that code of mine the current plot looks like this (no-log scale).
How can I modify my code so that it plots log-scale in its Y-axis?

The data can be downloaded [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?8o0qqy1vg5qs33u)

[image]

Comment: I searched "r logarithmic scale" with google and ended up at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245273/histogram-with-logarithmic-scale, https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-November/146367.html, or others...

Comment: I really think you should leave off the `print(dat)` when you know that the dataset is large. Should instead use `print(head(dat))` and `summary(dat)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the argument `log = "y"` to the call, but you'll have to change the minimum extents from zero to something higher. See `?plot.default` for details on this argument, which is passed along from `curve`.