# Histogram in R when x axis is very long and distribution is right-skewed

Tags: r, statistics, histogram, distribution

im trying to plot Historam using R

Data is like that:

myData <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,5,15000)

lets say I divided it into 3 buckets:

1-3
4-6
7-20000

so as a result the plot whould look like this:

```
-     
-     
-     
-     
-     
-     -
-     -     - 
1-3   3-6   6-20000
```

So I did sth like this:

```
hist(myData, breaks=c(1,3,6,20000), right=TRUE)
```

But the x axis in the result is so long that it is imposible to make histogram plot readeable.

Is it possible to make x scale non linear in this example just to show that there are 3 buckets and not 1-20000 long x axis scale ?

thank You very much for help

Comment: The issue is not that the x-axis is long, but that your data is very right-skewed, i.e. it has a long tail extending to the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cut`, rather than trying to manipulate `hist` directly :

```
myData <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,5,15000)

data <- data.frame(myData)

data <- transform(data, groupdata = cut(myData,
                                        breaks=c(1,3,6,20000),
                                        right=TRUE,include.lowest = TRUE))
library(ggplot2)
qplot(x = groupdata, data = data, stat = "bin")
```

[image: homemade histogram]

Comment: Oh great, but Ive got 2 questions: can I add labels to the x values ? for example: <=3, <=6, > 6 ? And second question: can I get numbers of each class obejcts ? so in this case it would be: 7, 2, 1. And hot to change count label w y axis ?

Comment: Oh for y axis it will be parameter: ylab :D

Comment: Oh I know that ading labels may be done by labels parameter in cut, so  the only thing left is hot to determine number ob objects in each class

Comment: all you had to do was `barplot(table(data$groupdata))`, why would you change the solution to ggplot when the question was in base R?

Comment: You're quite right, @rawr, that would also work -- and it seems like @gruber is more comfortable in base anyway.  I admit it -- I've been thinking in `ggplot` for so long I've forgotten some base-basics :P

Comment: Ok but How can I then get exact number of objects in each class ?

Comment: int @rawr soution it would be table(data$groupdata) but in AndrewMacDonald 's ?

Comment: yeah just do that after the `transform` step and @AndrewMacDonald, I can empathize. for me there was obviously a learning curve for ggplot, and I only thought in that for the longest time. recently, I have gone back to using minimal add-on packages, and very much prefer the ease of tweaking small details in base graphics

Comment: @rawr, ok but then I get sth like in the screenshot, I dont get sum of all elements in given interval: http://pl.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=f1hbx1&s=8#.U68Gbvl_scM

Answer (score 1):

```
yourData <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,5,15000)
```

adapting from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245273/histogram-with-logarithmic-scale):

```
h = hist(yourData,breaks = c(1,3,6,20000))
plot(h$counts,log="x",type='h',lwd=3,lend=2)
```

Comment: h$count is a vector of 3 elements. It stores the count for each bin.