# How to add log scale to y axis in histogram in R

Tags: r, histogram

How do I make the y-axis log 10 scale?
`hist(Data, breaks = 50)`
I'm very new to R programming, any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245273/histogram-with-logarithmic-scale-and-custom-breaks

Comment: It's difficult to log-scale the y-axis of bar plots and histograms because the y axis typically starts at 0, and `log(0)` is `-Inf`. Maybe try a square root scale instead?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1257851/190277

Answer (score 0):

Here are two potential options below.

1. The easiest way to plot on a log10 scale is to use the `scale_y_log10` if you are using `ggplot2` (ggplot2 reference here: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_continuous.html)
2. Apply the transformation to the data itself. Solutions using both `dplyr` and `base r` are listed below:

`dplyr`: `Data2 <- Data %>% mutate(logy = log10(yvariable))`

`base`:

`logy <- data.frame(log10(Data$yvariable))`

`Data2 <- cbind(Data, logy)`