# Histogram with log scale using csv in R

Tags: r, csv, histogram, logarithm, yaxis

I'm trying to create a `histogram` which will be identical to this [image]

My `csv` file contains 2 `columns` named *Value* & *Count*. I found similar [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245273/histogram-with-logarithmic-scale-and-custom-breaks) but I couldn't achieve results as the above image attached. My problem is that the y-axis doesn't have values like the above image attached. Also, how can I set the `x-axis` to get values from the column *Value*? Could you please help me? Here is the code:

```
test_csv = read.csv("dir/k.csv")

plot(k$Count, log="y", type='h', lwd=10, lend=2)
```

Here's my data:

```
test_csv = dput(k)
structure(list(Value = 1:101, Count = c(8512998L, 2524797L, 408468L, 
141472L, 72906L, 43135L, 29530L, 21288L, 16890L, 13181L, 10935L, 
8941L, 7883L, 6677L, 5995L, 5259L, 4802L, 4124L, 3912L, 3411L, 
3228L, 2761L, 2690L, 2335L, 2200L, 1878L, 1792L, 1586L, 1520L, 
1219L, 1232L, 1087L, 1027L, 895L, 845L, 761L, 781L, 712L, 676L, 
614L, 578L, 506L, 476L, 452L, 438L, 394L, 373L, 345L, 325L, 348L, 
320L, 257L, 260L, 219L, 227L, 213L, 177L, 182L, 170L, 151L, 135L, 
127L, 118L, 116L, 123L, 96L, 115L, 69L, 72L, 78L, 70L, 63L, 60L, 
64L, 67L, 50L, 63L, 64L, 63L, 49L, 53L, 45L, 48L, 48L, 40L, 56L, 
28L, 44L, 40L, 32L, 22L, 18L, 30L, 18L, 23L, 15L, 27L, 22L, 22L, 
21L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -101L))
```

And finally, here is what I produced [image: histogram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With packages like `scales` and `ggplot2` you can try this :

```
ggplot(k,aes(y=Count,x=Value))+geom_histogram(stat="identity")+scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))
```

You can feel free to change axis label using `xlab` and `ylab` function

Comment: Hi, I'm getting an error: 
```Error in trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x) : 
  could not find function "trans_breaks"
In addition: Warning message:
Ignoring unknown parameters: binwidth, bins, pad```

Comment: Import the `scales` package to have this function

Comment: It worked! i thought the ```scales``` pkg was loaded with the ```ggplot```. Many thanks